# How to prevent Visual Studio from breaking on all the awaits after it breaks on a deeper level Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, async-await

So what happens is this:

1. Visual Studio breaks on (for me, as an end-user) valid Exception five async/await methods deep.
2. This is behaviour that I like, because I can inspect state and see what is going on.
3. Usually this line is marked yellow.
4. When I press continue it will break again on every async/await in the upper stack. Marked as green, probably because the real stack is underneath, but that is my assumption.
5. These last ones I want to prevent, as this means I have to press 5 times F5 to continue, while not giving me more information then I could have figured out by *break 1*.

Is there any way to prevent 4 without disabling 1?

Note: this is an ASP.NET MVC application and this can be i.e. a background Ajax call.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this? Our "await chain" is even longer and with multiple requests breaking. So I currently have no other sensible way of escaping than dettaching the debugger

Comment: No I didn't find anything yet. I really don't understand why this is not a high priority and why it seems to affect so few people? It's driving me crazy - such a useless waste of time.

Comment: apparently I asked this question some other time - it has more upvotes, please upvote there too to get more attention: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62705626/asp-net-core-do-not-break-on-await-next-invoke-green-breaks

Comment: and here is VS Feedback item someone else made: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/exception-dialog-pops-up-multiple-times-for-same-e/739876

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are not `catch`ing the exception, and then it will bubble up through the call stack, *regardless if you inspected it using the debugger or not*. This is by design. There is no way to clear an exception that already occurred. The call stack is already in state of unwinding, and that is irreversible.

A solution might be to add a `try catch` with a conditional `throw`, like this:

```
try
{
    // code that may crash
}
catch
{
    // inspect the Exception here using VS
    var reThrow = true; // You can change reThrow to false while debugging
    if (reThrow) throw;
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your answer! I'm fine with the way how to code works, I just don't want to press *Continue* five times on the same Exception break. Yes, I know there is a SQL Connection error - no need to remind me five times in all `await`s :)

Comment: If the *only* workaround is to add a try/catch I would not do this - as I don't want to compromise code over the debugging experience. In a way I'm looking for something like "never break on parent awaits".